# Definitions Continuity Using the Order (Landau) symbolism.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics, order-theory

Is an $o(1)$ function always continuous?

Comment: No. It just means it has limit $0$

Comment: What is a $o(1)$ function?